# Разрешение доступа к скрипту в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, доступ

Ситуация такая.Поставлен запрет на отображение содержимого каталога при отсутствии индексного файла.Но нужно дать доступ к одному скрипту,крон будет запускать.

```js
<Files /cron/delivery_notice.php>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Files>
```

такое не работает.помогите,пожалуйста
З.Ы.

```html
php_value include_path .:../

Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#php_flag display_errors 1
#php_value error_reporting 6135

php_value session.cookie_domain myskbonus.ru


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    #чпу
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?dir=$1&page=index&action=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/|)$ index.php?dir=$1&page=index&action=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)(/|)$ index.php?dir=$1&page=$2&action=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z\_\-]+)(/|)$ index.php?dir=$1&page=$2&action=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dir=welcome&page=index&action=page404 [L]
    
    #Доступ к сайту только по HTTPS
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    
</IfModule>



# Включение PHP short_tag
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value short_open_tag 1
</IfModule>


<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|php|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
#Разрешить доступ к index.php всем
<Files index.php>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Files>
<Files api.php>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Files>
<Files "/cron/delivery_notice.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: У вас и запрет, и разрешение на доступ в одном .httaccess или разных?

Comment: @Visman в одном, сначала Options –Indexes , а потом ставлю разрашение

Comment: А зачем вы ставить разрешение, если ни чего не запрещали? Options –Indexes указывает, что не надо отображать файлы в каталоге, если  нет индексного файла. Но она не запрещает доступ к файлам при прямом обращении.

Comment: @Visman, есть еще такое(запрет) <FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|php|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Comment: Приведите полный файл htaccess, суть проблемы не ясна.

Comment: @GrayHoax апнул вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каталог `cron` поставьте такой .htaccess

```
Order Deny,Allow
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|php|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<Files delivery_notice.php>
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогло.

Comment: а как дать доступ к файлу в корне?

Comment: Если у вас на сервере файл delivery_notice.php в одном экземпляре, то можно так: <FilesMatch "^delivery_notice\.php$">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>